# How to autocomplete lua in vim?

Tags: vim, lua, autocomplete

I can't get lua to autocomplete in vim.
I tried lua-ftplugin which installs fine because I can perform one of its features, but when I type standard lua functions, it doesn't autocomplete.

What am I doing wrong?

I tried a clean vimrc with nothing but the lua plugin install:

```
call plug#begin()
Plug 'xolox/vim-misc'
Plug 'xolox/vim-lua-ftplugin'
call plug#end()
```

Comment: how are we supposed to know? We don't have your vimrc.

Comment: And why do you expect autocompletion?

Comment: @romainl Because the documentation of that plugin says that it should. https://vimawesome.com/plugin/vim-lua-ftplugin

Comment: No. It talks about "omni completion", Vim's built-in *manual* filetype-aware completion (see `:help ins-completion`), not "autocompletion", which is only available through third-party plugins.

Comment: @romainl Thank you. That's close enough to what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I know one indirect method to enable `vim-lua-ftplugin` autocompletion. Install [vim-mucomplete](https://github.com/lifepillar/vim-mucomplete) and enable `g:lua_complete_omni` option in .vimrc. But as described in `vim-lua-ftplugin` manual enabling this option may have undesired side effects. Also you can use [vim-luacomplete](https://github.com/SpaceVim/vim-luacomplete) plugin in pair with vim-mucomplete  instead of vim-lua-ftplugin.